# How do I write to a file inside a running docker container?

Tags: io-redirection, docker

With `cat` I can read from a file to stdout. This way I can for example pipe a file out of a docker container:

```
docker exec my_container cat file > file_on_host
```

When I want to do the opposite, I would need a command that reads from stdin and saves to a file. Is there such a command?

```
docker exec my_container ??? file < file_on_host
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar to your approach,

```
docker exec -i my_container dd of=file < file_on_host
```

which gives you a nice status summary and doesn't write the data to stdout.

There are probably a few other options,
e.g., `cp /dev/stdin file`
(which might not work,
depending on whether your container's OS supports `/dev/stdin`)
and `sh -c "cat > file"`.

Comment: Thank you for this solution! It's been running much faster than piping my content to the mongodb's shell running in the container! 

Answer (score 6):

`tee` can do that:

```
docker exec -i my_container tee file < file_on_host
```

The `-i` is necessary for stdin to work.

It will also output the file, which can be avoided by redirecting to the host's `/dev/null`:

```
docker exec -i my_container tee file < file_on_host > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually seems to be easier with :

`docker cp localfile.txt <CONTAINER ID>:/home/docker/data/`

Comment: I'm sure when I wrote the question there was something preventing me from using `docker cp`, maybe the `file_on_host` was actually stdout of another process. But for copying actual files this is of course the easiest solution.

Answer (score -1):

I must not have understood the question, because you can either use plain old redirection like you did the first time

`docker exec my_container < file_on_host > file`

or use `cat`  (again, with redirection).

Comment: That redirection happens between `docker` and `file` *on the host*. The `>` does not happen inside the container. If I wanted it to, it would involve quotes, which forces me to quote other quotes, so I don't like that solution.

Comment: I have no idea what a "container" is, or how it comes into play.  Your question was "read from stdin and save to a file".

Comment: this is similar to the sudo redirection problem and has the same answer.